# Sort fetchRequest with to-many relationship (Core Data)?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nssortdescriptor

Here you can the see the relationship between Item and Translation.

[image]

What I want to is to sort Items by Translation.name using a specific Translation.language. The result should be an ordered array with Items that is sorted in a specific language, e.g. English, German an so on.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

All you need to do is to fetch all the item translations with a sort descriptor

I am using a function I wrote in the past:

```
 +(NSArray*)fetchForEntity:(NSString*)entityName withPredicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate withSortDiscriptor:(NSString*)sortdDscriptorName{

NSManagedObjectContext *moc=[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription;

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

[request setPredicate:predicate];

if (sortdDscriptorName) {
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                        initWithKey:sortdDscriptorName ascending:YES];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
}

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray * requestArray =[moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (requestArray == nil)
{
    // Deal with error...
}
return requestArray;

   }
```

In your case you should use call it this way:

```
 NSString *languageName = @"German"; //or what ever
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"language ==   %@",languageName];

 NSArray *array = [self fetchForEntity:@"Translation" withPredicate:predicate withSortDiscriptor:@"name"];
```

Now you have a list of all the translations in the German language.
Then you can get all the items you need with:

```
  NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
 [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   Translation *translation = (Translation*)obj;
   Item *item = translation.item;
  [itemsArray addObject:item];
 }];
```

Hope it helps
Shani

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but that doesn't work. I'm getting this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'`. It's because of the translations (to-many) relationship.

Comment: I also forgot to say that I want to sort by translations.name. In your answer you wrote translations.language but this should not make a big difference.

Comment: Edited my answer. I hope it will fit your needs now

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked. Thought that could be solved easier without iterating any Translation.